# exact meaning of 你自以为的极限只是别人的起点

Tags: meaning

the translation for this sentence 你自以为的极限只是别人的起点 is "your peak is just the beginning for others". this is about a love story the guy just gave up chasing the girl and the girl said this sentence to him. what i'm confused is does she mean your peak is the begining of other people to court her? or does she mean the guy's peak is suppose to be just the beginning as a reference in courting rituals here in China? so technically is the girl saying you and i dating is just the start you gave up too easily?

Comment: 你自以为的极限 should be "The peak you thought". That means the boy thought that he has come to an end, a peak in his stage. 別人的起点, "the beginning for others", implies he could have another love story. [Based on my guess only :) ]

Comment: another love story with another girl?

Comment: Yes if by looking at this one sentence only. But I don't know what the love story is about so I'm not sure

Comment: not with her?or maybe she is implying the guy still has a chance with her?

Comment: Without knowing the story content, I can't tell

Comment: basically the guy gave up because they lived in different states here in China.they kissed and held hands but she needed to move and doesn't know when she will comeback to that state again.guy had enough and told her i'm leaving good bye thanks. don't you think the girl is telling the guy is moving to fast? because dating here in China takes a long time? that's the story

Comment: @epiconside:  The sentence could be a blame for like you said the girl is telling the guy is moving to fast. Or it could be for other reasons. Maybe, after the sentence, what the girl said has some clues. Usually, we have to feel the speaker's tone along with other factors (like the reasons behind, situations, etc.)to decide. I think you got that sentence meaning and you could figure this out at your discretion. lol

Answer (score 1):

> "你自以为的极限只是别人的起点"
>
> "The limit you thought you had reached, is just a starting point for some other people."

She was saying the guy gave up too easily.

He thought he had reached the limit of his ability to continue on with this relationship; The woman disagreed, suggesting the level of obstacle this guy facing was no more than a starting point of a challenge in many people's eyes.

*A challenge get harder and harder after it started. But the starting point of a challenge is easy--  all you have to do, is to 'decide to take it on.'*

Answer (score 0):

I gather that there would be some other guys to chase that girl at the same time in that story, or that girl has the friend(s)(girls) who was/were chasing by someone else as well.

So, for comparison, the girl feels what that guy had done for her (court her) could not compete with other guys (who chasing her/others), although that guy thought he already done everything he could (reach the peak point). Others can go far further beyond what that guy could do (as his peak is just the beginning point of others).

Answer (score -1):

This is also the title of a (translated?) book. The english title is "break out"[image]

Comment: Well, the sentence is being used differently here. Here it is used to encourage people to break out their limitations, hence break out/keep making progress. I down-voted it for not distracting from OP's context.